# How to Remove characters that doesn't match the string pattern from a column of a data frame

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a column in my data frame as shown below.

[image]

I want to keep the data in the pattern "\\d+Zimmer" and remove all the digits from the column such as "9586" and "927" in the picture.
I tried following gsub function.

```
gsub("[^\\d+Zimmer]", "", flat_cl_one$rooms)
```

But it removes all the digits, as below.

[image]

What Regex can I use to get the correct result? Thank You in Advance

Comment: Do you want to remove rows, remove leading digits, both, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace strings that don't contain the word "Zimmer"

```r
flat_cl_one$room[!grepl("Zimmer", flat_cl_one$room)] <- ""

flat_cl_one
#>       room
#> 1  3Zimmer
#> 2  2Zimmer
#> 3  2Zimmer
#> 4  3Zimmer
#> 5         
#> 6         
#> 7  3Zimmer
#> 8  6Zimmer
#> 9  2Zimmer
#> 10 4Zimmer
```

---

**Data**

```r
flat_cl_one <- data.frame(room = c("3Zimmer", "2Zimmer", "2Zimmer", "3Zimmer", 
                                   "9586", "927", "3Zimmer", "6Zimmer", 
                                   "2Zimmer", "4Zimmer"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can coerce any rows that have alphanumeric characters to `NA` and then replace the rows that don't have `NA` to blanks.

```
library(dplyr)

flat_cl_one %>% 
  mutate(rooms = ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(rooms)), "", rooms))
```

Or we can use `str_detect`:

```
flat_cl_one %>% 
  mutate(rooms = ifelse(str_detect(rooms, "Zimmer", negate = TRUE), "", rooms))
```

**Output**

```
        rooms
1   647Zimmer
2   394Zimmer
3            
4            
5 38210Zimmer
```

We could do the same thing with `filter` if you wanted to actually remove those rows.

```
flat_cl_one %>% 
  filter(is.na(as.numeric(rooms)))

#        rooms
#1   647Zimmer
#2   394Zimmer
#3 38210Zimmer
```

**Data**

```
flat_cl_one <- structure(list(rooms = c("647Zimmer", "394Zimmer", "8796", "9389", 
"38210Zimmer")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using `stringr::str_extract` (I am using @AndrewGillreath-Brown's data, to whom I thank):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(
  list(rooms = c("647Zimmer", "394Zimmer", "8796", "9389", "38210Zimmer")),
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df %>% 
  mutate(rooms = str_extract(rooms, "\\d+Zimmer"))

#>         rooms
#> 1   647Zimmer
#> 2   394Zimmer
#> 3        <NA>
#> 4        <NA>
#> 5 38210Zimmer
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern `[^\\d+Zimmer]` matches any character except a digit or the following characters `+` `Z` `i` `m` etc...

Using gsub, you can check if the string does not start with the pattern `^\\d+Zimmer` using a negative lookahead `(?!` setting `perl = TRUE` and then match 1 or more digits if the assertion it true.

```
gsub("^(?!^\\d+Zimmer\\b)\\d+\\b", "", flat_cl_one$rooms, perl = TRUE)
```

See an [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py0nsSQ@OSc@Py9VwUZXISWxJFEvrSgxN1WjKD8/t1jBViFZQ8k4KjM3N7VISUdByQgrE0mBpamFGZg2MkeTMcOq1QTK1NTkSi8uTdJQitOwV4yLiUnRhkjExCRpgnggtUCM5F4VsAt1FApSi3KA7gwJCnXV5OL6/x8A).

Comment: Thank you, it almost solves my issue.  I need to keep strings, in this pattern as well, Ex: “3.5 – 4.5Zimmer “. When I run the above code, I lose this part "3.5 "

Comment: @manojrasika In that case the pattern could be `^(?!^\\d+(?:\\s*-\\s*\\d+)?Zimmer\\b)\\d+`See this [demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py0nsSQ@OSc@Py9VwUZXISWxJFEvrSgxN1WjKD8/t1jBViFZQ8k4KjM3N7VISUdByQgrE0mBpamFGZg2MkeTMcOq1QTJFD1ThUcNkxVM9EyhgpqaXOnFpUkaSnEa9opxMTEp2hr2VjExxVq6IALE17SHKI2JSdIE8UHmADGSt1TAHtFRKEgtygF6JyQo1FWTi@v/fwA)